# Can someone explain why R dispatches the S3 method for this object's super class rather than the sub class?

Tags: r, oop, package

In this example, there is some subtlety going on with package namespaces and S3 dispatches that I cannot understand. Can someone with deep knowledge on the subject please explain to me in simple terms, why R is dispatching `as.tags.htmlwidget` for this object instead of `as.tags.rdeckControls`?

```r
library(rdeck.controls) ##remotes::install_github("qfes/rdeck.controls")
library(htmltools)
library(sloop)
library(purrr)

foo_widget <-
  structure(list(x = list(targetRDeckId = "mitigation_activity",
    controlType = "dropdown", controlData = list(layerNames = c("Mitigation activity: All",
    "Mitigation activity: Community Education", "Mitigation activity: Fire Breaks or Trails",
    "Mitigation activity: Hazard Reduction"), layerGroupNames = character(0),
        initialSelection = "Mitigation activity: All", label = "")),
    width = "100%", height = "1em !important", sizingPolicy = list(
        defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL, padding = 
NULL,
        viewer = list(defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL,
            padding = NULL, fill = TRUE, suppress = FALSE, paneHeight = NULL),
        browser = list(defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL,
            padding = NULL, fill = FALSE, external = FALSE), 
        knitr = list(defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL,
            figure = TRUE)), dependencies = NULL, elementId = NULL,
    preRenderHook = NULL, jsHooks = list()), class = c("rdeckControls",
"htmlwidget"), package = "rdeck.controls")

methods("as.tags")
#>  [1] as.tags.character*          as.tags.default*           
#>  [3] as.tags.html*               as.tags.html_dependency*   
#>  [5] as.tags.htmlwidget*         as.tags.list*              
#>  [7] as.tags.rdeckControls       as.tags.shiny.tag*         
#>  [9] as.tags.shiny.tag.function* as.tags.shiny.tag.list*    
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
s3_dispatch(as.tags(foo_widget))
#> => as.tags.rdeckControls
#>  * as.tags.htmlwidget
#>  * as.tags.default
error <- purrr::safely(function(x) as.tags(foo_widget))(foo_widget)
error
#> $result
#> NULL
#> 
#> $error
#> <simpleError in validateCssUnit(sizeInfo$height): "1em !important" is not a valid CSS unit (e.g., "100%", "400px", "auto")>
#
# this means as.tags.htmlWidget was run
#
str(as.tags.rdeckControls(foo_widget))
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ :List of 3
#>   .. ..$ name    : chr "div"
#>   .. ..$ attribs :List of 3
#>   .. .. ..$ id   : chr "htmlwidget-debd00a6269d494de569"
#>   .. .. ..$ style: chr "width:100%;height:1em !important;"
#>   .. .. ..$ class: chr "rdeckControls html-widget"
#>   .. ..$ children: list()
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.tag.list" "list"
#>  $ :List of 3
#>   ..$ name    : chr "script"
#>   ..$ attribs :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ type    : chr "application/json"
#>   .. ..$ data-for: chr "htmlwidget-debd00a6269d494de569"
#>   ..$ children:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : 'html' chr "{\"x\":{\"targetRDeckId\":\"mitigation_activity\",\"controlType\":\"dropdown\",\"controlData\":{\"layerNames\":"| __truncated__
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "html")= logi TRUE
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
#>  $ : NULL
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "shiny.tag.list" "list"
#>  - attr(*, "html_dependencies")=List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ name      : chr "htmlwidgets"
#>   .. ..$ version   : chr "1.5.3"
#>   .. ..$ src       :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ file: chr "C:/Users/msmcbain/libs/R/htmlwidgets/www"
#>   .. ..$ meta      : NULL
#>   .. ..$ script    : chr "htmlwidgets.js"
#>   .. ..$ stylesheet: NULL
#>   .. ..$ head      : NULL
#>   .. ..$ attachment: NULL
#>   .. ..$ package   : NULL
#>   .. ..$ all_files : logi TRUE
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
#>   ..$ :List of 10
#>   .. ..$ name      : chr "rdeckControls-binding"
#>   .. ..$ version   : chr "0.2.0"
#>   .. ..$ src       :List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ file: chr "C:/Users/msmcbain/libs/R/rdeck.controls/htmlwidgets"
#>   .. ..$ meta      : NULL
#>   .. ..$ script    : chr "rdeckControls.js"
#>   .. ..$ stylesheet: NULL
#>   .. ..$ head      : NULL
#>   .. ..$ attachment: NULL
#>   .. ..$ package   : NULL
#>   .. ..$ all_files : logi FALSE
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
#>  - attr(*, "browsable_html")= logi TRUE
#
# This works if called directly
#
as.tags.rdeckControls <- function(x) as.character(x)
as.tags(foo_widget)
#> [1] "list(targetRDeckId = \"mitigation_activity\", controlType = \"dropdown\", controlData = list(layerNames = c(\"Mitigation activity: All\", \"Mitigation activity: Community Education\", \"Mitigation activity: Fire Breaks or Trails\", \"Mitigation activity: Hazard Reduction\"), layerGroupNames = character(0), initialSelection = \"Mitigation activity: All\", label = \"\"))"
#> [2] "100%"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#> [3] "1em !important"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#> [4] "list(defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL, padding = NULL, viewer = list(defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL, padding = NULL, fill = TRUE, suppress = FALSE, paneHeight = NULL), browser = list(defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL, padding = NULL, fill = FALSE, external = FALSE), knitr = list(defaultWidth = NULL, defaultHeight = NULL, figure = TRUE))"     
#> [5] "NULL"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#> [6] "NULL"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#> [7] "NULL"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#> [8] "list()"
#
# and if defined locally
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NAMESPACE file did not declare the method as an S3 method. Also there's no need to explicitly export it (most S3 methods are not exported).

So rather than

```
export(as.tags.rdeckControls)
```

You should have

```
S3method(as.tags, rdeckControls)
```

roxygen should take care of that for you most of the time. The problem here might be that it can't tell what's the function name and what's the class because of the extra `.` in the function name. You should be able to disambiguate with

```
@method as.tags rdeckControls
```

when documenting that function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did generate the documentation and namespace with `devtools::document()` it seems that roxygen did not figure out it was an S3 method. I don't think your advice is correct about @export, see: https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/namespace.html. I found a similar example and it used the @method tag which I had never seen before. The documentation for it isn't great but I think it's how you're meant to handle cases like this.

Comment: Acutally, sorry I think you are right about export. Within the roxygen framework the @export tag must be used, but it seems that when it properly detects an S3 method it does not put an export() in the NAMESPACE for it.

Comment: Yeah. I can see how that is confusing. The `export()` in the NAMESPACE file is different from the `@export` used by roxygen which is an unfortunate mismatch. But in the end what matters is what winds up in the NAMESPACE file.